# Pandas Groupby.sum() avoid Duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

df1

```
Check#  Date     Amount   Payment
100     12/1/16  $1,000   ($1,000)
201     12/8/16  $1,200   ($900)
201     12/8/16  $1,200   ($100)
301     12/5/16  $450     ($450)
```

What I'm trying to do is separate into another dataframe any check that has not been fully paid with the current outstanding amount(Amount - Payment).

For example, I would like the above df1 to return:

df2

```
Check #   Date      Amount
201       12/8/16   $200
```

I've tried running a Groupby.sum() on check a new column labeled New_Check(Amount + Payment) but I end up with Check 201 being $2,400 which is not what I want.

Any ideas?  I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the amount of the check and the sum of all payments:

```
df2 = df1.groupby('Check').agg(
    {'Date': 'first', 'Amount': 'first', 'Payment': 'sum'}
).reset_index(level=1)
```

Then filter:

```
df2['Amount'] = df2['Amount'] + df2['Payment']
df2 = df2[df2['Amount'] > 0].drop('Payment', axis=1)
```

Comment: This gives me 2 columns, Amount and Payment.  I think the filter may not work properly.  I want the net of Amount + Payment and don't need any of the Checks that were fully paid(Amount + Payment = 0).

Answer (score 2):

You can just add Amount to the group and then use `query` to keep the method chaining

```
#create data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Check#':[100,201,201,301],
              'Date':['12-1-2016', '12-8-2016', '12-8-2016', '12-5-2-16'],
              'Amount':[1000,1200,1200,450],
              'Payment' : [-1000, -900, -100, -450]})

grouped = df.groupby(['Check#', 'Date','Amount'])

grouped.sum() \
       .reset_index() \
       .query("Amount != -Payment") \
       .assign(net = lambda x: x['Amount'] + x['Payment'])
```

Output

```
   Check#       Date  Amount  Payment  net
1     201  12-8-2016    1200    -1000  200
```

Comment: This gives me a syntax error on     query("Amount != -Payment")

Comment: Check now. I've added code for the dataframe that I created before the answer.

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't mirror your output. =/

Comment: It could be a versioning issue. Check `pd.__version__`. Pandas is currently at 0.19.1. `query` is still experimental

Comment: Using pandas 0.18.1